# Output formats for QGIS Heatmap plugin not appearing in drop-drown in Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, heat-map, qgis-2.8

I've been trying to use the heatmap plugin on QGIS (2.8.2) on Ubuntu(14.04) but the drop down for the output formats doesn't get populated.

Selecting the drop-down allows me to press OK on the plugin popup which gives "GDAL driver error: Cannot open the driver for the specified format".

I've installed GDAL according to [this](http://www.sarasafavi.com/installing-gdalogr-on-ubuntu.html). The drop down gets populated and works as expected in Windows. How can get the same to work on Ubuntu?

Update : I've tested on a different Ubuntu (14.04) machine and it worked as expected, so the problem seems to be occurring on only some machines

Comment: I just started having this issue as well... Ubuntu, QGIS 2.8.2

Comment: me too (Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: Same issue for me as GDAL seems to be properly installed... I'm on Linux Mint (Ubuntu 14.04) and QGIS 2.12. Any advice from Linux users would be very appreciated!

Comment: @wiltomap I vaguely remember having this problem a while back, although this sort of thing is very difficult to reproduce. Looking at the screenshots in [a very similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/167257/55203), my gut tells me to check Help>About and make sure the versions are the same in "Compiled against GDAL/OGR" and "Running against GDAL/OGR"?

Comment: Same problem in QGIS 2.12.2

Comment: Same problem in QGIS 2.14