# Output formats not showing in heatmap plugin (QGis 2.10.1 in ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, heat-map

I just upgraded to QGIS 2.10 (using the debian repos) and the heatmap plugin doesn't show any formats in the dropdown menu.

I'm able to open every raster format I have at hand and, of course, the drivers are listed in the gdal driver options.

I looked around and found a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147748/output-formats-for-qgis-heatmap-plugin-not-appearing-in-drop-drown-in-ubuntu) but refering to QGIS 2.8 and without any answers.

Comment: Another question you may want to reference is here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167257/workarounds-for-heatmap-plugin-in-qgis

Comment: Yes, that seems like a duplicate