# Workarounds for heatmap plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2, heat-map

In QGIS 2.8, the heatmap plugin got CRS broken. I updated to 2.10, now in the plugin the dialog is broken: it does not let you choose the format.

I render layers for atlases with heatmap style. But I need to export it to GeoTIFF, and I don't see a way to do this.

Updating the QGIS is not easy in Ubuntu, since it works normally when installed from a PPA, but installing from sources, or downloading debs is  very painful.

Is there a workaround?

A command line example will do too.

**edit** here's a screenshot. The format list is empty, and if I write file extension manually as I did here, it still does not allow, showing a message that format is not chosen.

[image: Screenshot: format dropdown is empty]

Meanwhile in another dialog, format choice works correctly:

[image]

Versions: 
[image: Versions]
[image]

Comment: I just opened 2.10 and output a heatmap raster (using the `Raster→Heatmap→Heatmap…` menu). The dialog allowed me to select the format. Can you provide more information or a screenshot, because I can't confirm your issue.

Comment: Additionally, are you looking for advice on how to update QGIS on Ubuntu? I'm not sure what you mean by the remark, since it appears that you already *have* updated to 2.10. Do you mean that you installed but source but would rather use the package manager?

Comment: @LeeHachadoorian see the screenshot in the question. I installed it from PPA (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

I am running QGIS 2.10 on Linux Mint 17.2 (based on trusty), and in the Heatmap plugin the available formats dropdown is not empty, so your problem is not a general problem with QGIS running on LM/Ubuntu. I'm not sure how to reproduce this problem.

However, you suggest that the issue arose after an update to 2.10. It occurs to me that a significant amount of QGIS functionality (esp. for plugins) is dependent upon `python-qgis`. This *could* explain the difference between Heatmap (plugin) and Raster Calculator (which I believe is core), so I would check that you have `python-qgis` that installed with

```
apt-cache policy python-qgis
```

and install it if it is missing.

Another concern is that you say that you updated to 2.10 from the [ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable) PPA. However, as far as I can tell, ubuntugis-unstable only goes up to version 2.8. Not sure why this would lead to incomplete functionality. Maybe you have QGIS 2.10 but `python-qgis` 2.8? The discrepancy does imply that you may not have installed from the repository that you intended.

If you are running Ubuntu Trusty, I would recommend installing 2.10 from the QGIS repository, but begin by purging your current installation:

```
sudo apt-get purge qgis python-qgis
```

Then add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
```

Note: although you can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` directly, in practice I prefer to use the Software Sources tool (available standalone or from the Synaptic menu) to add new repository source lines.

After doing that, update and reinstall `qgis` and `python-qgis` packages via Synaptic or:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

These instructions taken from http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. I can also confirm that they work, as that is how I got QGIS 2.10 installed on LM 17.2. This is also the instructions for the version designed to work with ubuntugis dependencies, and requires the use of the ubuntugis-unstable PPA, which you are already using. But if you are using a more recent Ubuntu release than Trusty, you have to pick the appropriate version, and *not* use ubuntugis dependencies. Check the link for further instructions.

Comment: I checked, the version was 2.10.1 and `python-qgis: Installed: 1:2.10.1+20trusty`, then reproduced all the steps, it installed without issues, and unfortunately, there's still the same problem with heatmap dialog. I launched `qgis.bin` from shell just to see if there are exception messages, but there's nothing.

Comment: Reinstalled `gdal-bin` the same way, still no effect.

Comment: Sorry, it was a stab in the dark. Might be worth posting to qgis-user mailing list.